# How to replace radio buttons with images that also includes a submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am simply attempting to replace my radio buttons with images and include a submit button. Unfortunately my submit button becomes deactivated and my radio buttons do not check all the time. Is this fixable?

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("img[id='img2']").css({"display": "none"});
     $("img[id='img4']").css({"display": "none"});
     $("img[id='img6']").css({"display": "none"});


    $("img[id=img1]").click(function(){
        $("img[id='img2']").show().css({"display": "block"});
        $(this).prev().attr('checked',true);
        $("img[id='img4']").hide();
        $("img[id='img6']").hide();


    });
    $("img[id='img3']").click(function(){
        $("img[id='img4']").show().css({"display": "block"});
        $(this).prev().attr('checked',true);
        $("img[id='img2']").hide();
        $("img[id='img6']").hide();

    });
   $("img[id='img5']").click(function(){
        $("img[id='img6']").show().css({"display": "block"});
        $(this).prev().attr('checked',true);
        $("img[id='img2']").hide();
        $("img[id='img4']").hide();

    });


  });

</script>
```

CSS:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="subscribeForm" action="{{URL::route('star-update')}}">

        <input type="radio"  value="1.0" name="imagename" style="display:none"><img id="img1" src="boxone.png">
        <img id="img2" src="picone.png" style="position:absolute">

        <input type="radio" value="1.5" name="imagename" style="display:none"><img id="img3" src="boxtwo.png">
       <img id="img4" src="pictwo.png" style="position:absolute">

        <input type="radio" value="2" name="imagename" style="display:none"> <img id="img5" src="boxthree.png">
       <img id="img6" src="picthree.png" style="position:absolute">

{{Form::token()}} 
    <br>
  <input name="submit" type="submit"  value="submit">
   </form>
```

Comment: totally unnecessary to do `show()` and `css({"display": "block"});` at the same time as both do the same thing...

Comment: have you tried `type="hidden"` for your input buttons instead of actually hiding them? I'm not 100% sure now but I think inputs that are "display:none" will be disabled by default (citation needed)...

Comment: Thanks that does work but it means I have to delete my position of absolute for each image. This is actually part of my styling. It's my styling that is giving me the problem. Big thanks btw

Comment: added it as an answer... ;)

Comment: Sorry I thought it was fixed. The radio button do not act as radio buttons but the submit button is now active

Comment: you're going to have to do a better job at explaining what exactly you're trying to achieve, and what is not working... and how you changed your code recently; maybe include that at the bottom of your post as an edit...?

Comment: please either update the question with more details if still not resolved, or accept my answer as the correct one if it addressed the originally asked question... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `type="hidden"` on your inputs instead of hiding them via CSS (`display: none`).

Hiding an input via CSS will basically make it disabled for the form.